# Cast String to a value obtained using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, java-8

So I'm getting a value that I know is an String from another class using reflection, but when I try to cast (String) to it, a ClassCastException is thrown as String cannot be cast to field. Can someone help me?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException {
    Utils utils = new Utils();
    Field field = utils.getClass().getDeclaredField("myString");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    String myString = (String) field;
}
```

Comment: `String s = (String)field.get(whateverInstanceOfTheClass)`?

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException {
        Utils utils = new Utils();
        Field field = utils.getClass().getDeclaredField("myString");
        
        field.setAccessible(true);
        String myString = (String) field;
    }

Answer (score 3):

So, `field` is an object of `java.lang.reflect.Field` . So you can't cast it to String. You need to get the string object from `utils`. To do that you should use `Field#get()` method which takes the `object` (in your case it will be `utils`) as an argument.

```
String myString = (String) field.get(utils);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String myString = (String) field.get(utils);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `(String) field.get(utils);` instead of `(String) field;`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20488871)

Comment: Does it now answer the question?